# same word added twice

Tags: c++, file-io, eof

In C++, I am trying to read through a file and store the strings from that file into a string in the program. This works great until I get to the last word, which is always stored twice.

```
ifstream inputStream;
string next = "";
string allMsg = "";
inputStream.open(fileName.c_str());
string x;

while (!inputStream.eof())
{
    inputStream >> x;
    next = next + " " + x;
}
cout << "The entire message, unparsed, is: " << next << endl;
```

Doing this adds the last word or int from the file I open to next. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you read the last line, it won't set eof bit and the fail bit, only when you read the **END**, eof bit is set and `eof()` returns true.

```
while (!inputStream.eof())  // at the eof, but eof() is still false
{
    inputStream >> x;  // this fails and you are using the last x
    next = next + " " + x;
}
```

change it to

```
while( inputStream >> x){
    // inputStream >> x;  dont call this again!
    next = next + " " + x;
}
```

Comment: This isn't working because it is now only reading in every other word. So if the file said "one two three four five", it now only stores "one three five" into next.

Comment: you don't call `inputStream >> x;` inside the loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!inputStream.eof())
```

Should be

```
while (inputStream >> x)
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 - that has already been answered many many times:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score -1):

eof() will return true if the last read hit the end of file, not if the next read will hit the end of file. Try:

```
ifstream inputStream;
string next = "";
string allMsg = "";
inputStream.open(fileName.c_str());
string x;

inputStream >> x;
if(!inputStream.eof()) {
    do {
        next = next + " " + x;
        inputStream >> x;
    } while (!inputStream.eof())
}
cout << "The entire message, unparsed, is: " << next << endl;
```

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  Zac Wrangler's is accurate and more complete.  This one is just wrong.